# Ionic2 on-tap disables content scrolling

Tags: events, scroll, ionic2

In my Ionic2 app, I have an `on-tap` event on a div inside the `<ion-content>` block. The page is larger than the viewport and therefore should scroll. However, when trying to scroll by touching the div with the `on-tap` event the page doesn't move (it does move when scrolling outside the div).

```
<ion-content>
    scrolls
    <div on-tap="tapped()">
        doesn't scroll
    </div>
    scrolls
</ion-content>
```

Does the `on-tap` event stop event propagation all together?

What am I missing?

Comment: I ran into this recently myself.  Basically, it's an issue with Hammer.js ... change `(tap)="tapped()"` to (click)="tapped()" and it should work.  Not putting this as an answer because it's just a workaround.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, thanks! I have a feeling now (though it isn't clear from the documentation) that the "gestures" (tap, pan, slide, etc.) are meant to stop event propagation. It surely makes sense for panning thought not so sure about the remaining ones. `(click)="tapped()"` is indeed how my kind of scenario is implemented in the Ionic2 tutorial template (`ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2`).

Comment: This is a simple bug that will be fixed eventually ... until then.  Glad I could help.

Comment: I change click to tap, because of slow work on ios devices and have the same problem. Same problem - there is no content scroll in that case. Have you solved it?